# Byobu skeleton files?

Tags: byobu

I noticed that on first usage of `byobu`, the utility created the `~/.byobu` directory and pre-populate it with various configuration files.

Where do these files came from, though? I'd like to customize them so that any new invocation of `byobu` use a set of files we have pre-created (and managed via SaltStack).

In other words, I want to customize the "skeleton" files for byobu.

Answer (score 0):

If I have to guess, they are the files in `/usr/share/byobu`. This directory has subdirectories with names matching the names of the files in `~/.byoby`.

You can list the files that `byobu` has installed on your system using:

```
dpkg-query -L byobu
```

Alternatively, unless you've done an `apt-get clean`, the `byobu` package will still be in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

```
dpkg-deb -c /var/cache/apt/archives/byobu*.deb
```